# Search component render problem with validate js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have search component with validate js.

Problem: when my input in foucs first time, validate and request dont work, but when i lose focus my input, and click it again, and try again, search working without validation

```
interface IProps {
    onSearchChange?: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
}

const Search: React.FC<IProps> = ({ onSearchChange }) => {
    const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    const [inputIsTouched, setInputIsTouched] = useState(false);

    const currentValue = inputRef.current?.value && inputRef.current.value;

    const validateErrors = validate({ currentValue }, constraints);

    const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (validateErrors?.currentValue) {
            return;
        }

        currentValue && onSearchChange && onSearchChange(event);
        setInputIsTouched(true);
    };

    const debouncedOnChange = debounce(handleChange, 1000);

    return (
        <div className={classes['Root']}>
            <Input
                type="text"
                autoComplete="off"
                placeholder="..."
                onChange={debouncedOnChange}
                ref={inputRef}
                onBlur={() => setInputIsTouched(true)}
                isError={inputIsTouched && !!validateErrors?.currentValue}
            />

            <div className={classes['ErrorContainer']}>
                {inputIsTouched && validateErrors?.currentValue && (
                    <Text color="error" size="s">
                        {validateErrors.currentValue}
                    </Text>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's expected because on first render, `currentValue` is `undefined` (as `inputRef.current` is `null`) and there's nothing calling `handleChange` to trigger the search.

You need to make sure the `handleChange` logic also runs on the initial render, so it should look something like this:

```
const Search: React.FC<IProps> = ({ onSearchChange }) => {

    // Use a single object for all input state props:
    const [{
      isTouched,
      validateErrors,
    }, setInputState] = useState({
      isTouched: false,
      validateErrors: null,
    });
    
    const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    // Debounce only search callback:
    const debouncedSearchChange = debounce(onSearchChange, 1000);

    const handleChange = useCallback((e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        // Get the current value:
        const currentValue = e.currentTarget.value;
        
        // Validate it:
        const validateErrors = validate({ currentValue }, constraints);
        
        if (validateErrors?.currentValue) {
            // And handle error:
            setInputState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, validateErrors }));
            
            return;
        }
        
        // Or success:
        setInputState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, validateErrors: null }));

        // And trigger the debounced search if needed:
        if (currentValue && debouncedSearchChange ) debouncedSearchChange(event);
    }, [constraints, debouncedSearchChange]);
    
    // Trigger validation and search on first render:
    useEffect(() => {        
        const inputElement = inputRef.current;
        
        // TypeScript will complain about this line, so you might want to 
        // re-structure the logic above to accommodate this:
        if (inputElement) handleChange({ currentTarget: inputElement });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={classes['Root']}>
            <Input
                type="text"
                autoComplete="off"
                placeholder="..."
                onChange={handleChange}
                ref={inputRef}
                onBlur={() => setInputState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, isTouched: true }))}
                isError={inputIsTouched && !!validateErrors?.currentValue}
            />

            <div className={classes['ErrorContainer']}>
                {inputIsTouched && validateErrors?.currentValue && (
                    <Text color="error" size="s">
                        {validateErrors.currentValue}
                    </Text>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```